# HTTPS data retrieval error

Tags: http, https, esp8266, nodemcu

I have an ESP12 with `NodeMCU` firmware installed (modules: `http`, `tls`, etc.).

Whenever I try to use [http.get](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/http/#httpget) with an https link, I receive the following error:

```
> http.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/cAB83eF1", nil, function(code, data)
>> if (code < 0) then
>> print("HTTP request failed")
>> else
>> print(code, data)
>> end
>> end)
> HTTP client: Disconnected with error: -114
HTTP client: Connection timeout
HTTP client: Connection timeout
```

where as when I tried the same `pastebin.com` link without https, I am able to receive data and the HTTP status code.

```
> http.get("http://pastebin.com/raw/cAB83eF1", nil, function(code, data)
>> if (code < 0) then
>> print("HTTP request failed")
>> else
>> print(code, data)
>> end
>> end)
> 200   test
```

Quoting from the [docs of http.get](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/http/):

> Each request method takes a callback which is invoked when the
>   response has been received from the server. The first argument is the
>   status code, which is either a regular HTTP status code, or -1 to
>   denote a DNS, connection or out-of-memory failure, or a timeout
>   (currently at 10 seconds).

Since the docs say valid codes are -1 and HTTP codes, how can I find out what is -114?

**Edit1**: After building the firmware with debug option ON. I get the following error:

```
> http.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/cAB83eF1", nil, function(code, data)
>> if (code < 0) then
>> print("HTTP request failed")
>> else
>> print(code, data)
>> end
>> end)
> client handshake start.
please start sntp first !
please start sntp first !
client handshake failed!
Reason:[-0x7200]
HTTP client: Disconnected with error: -114
HTTP client: Connection timeout
HTTP client: Connection timeout
=rtctime.get()
1501394767  272709
>
```

As per the log statement `Reason:[-0x7200]` 0x72 hex is -114 decimal which gets printed later `Disconnected with error: -114`.

Also `sntp.sync()` has already been performed as seen from the output of `rtctime.get()`. Even if the SNTP has been synced why is the message `please start sntp first !` printed?

Also later in the log, after the -114 message, it displays `Connection timeout` message. How can I change the timeout for https connections? any pointers to C/header files?

Note: I do have the git repo and docker image installed on my Linux machine for building the firmware.

PS: I need https because I'll be making my ESP12 communicate with a RESP API hosted on the cloud.

Comment: Does the image have curl setup? Can you try and see what `curl -v https://pastebin.com/raw/cAB83eF1` give you?

Comment: There are lot of open issues i see related to HTTPS failing. try adding this to your code tls.cert.verify(false) before the get command.

https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1915

Comment: @TarunLalwani still the same error

Comment: @ritesht93 would you mind accepting the answer so that this doesn't keep showing up in my "open NodeMCU questions" list?

Comment: @Marcel sure no issues. Will track its status on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short and unsatisfactory answer: you hit https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1707.